# how to total up the number in each row

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

db table

[image]

in the database example picture how can i total up the number in the column
for example : 9+2+1+1+..... = ??

```js
public function graph()
  {
    $statistics = DiraStatistics::all();
    $labels = [];
    $data = [];
    $data1 = [];
    $data2 = [];
    $data3 = [];
    foreach ($statistics as $key => $statistic) {
        array_push($labels,$statistic->date_access);
        array_push($data,$statistic->question_asked);
        array_push($data1,$statistic->low_confidence);
        array_push($data2,$statistic->no_answer);
        array_push($data3,$statistic->missing_intent);
    }
     return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('labels','data','data1','data2','data3'));
  }
```

i have called the table as shown

Comment: Have you tried to query the database? what is the SQL select you have tried, if any?

Comment: Depends if you need the data and the sum: you either compute it manually while appending in a given array or make a separate query using `SUM()` -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following code to retrieve sum

```
public function graph()
{
    $statistics = DiraStatistics::all();
    $question_asked_sum = $statistics->sum('question_asked');
    $labels = $statistics->pluck('date_access');
    $data = $statistics->pluck('question_asked');
    $data1 = $statistics->pluck('low_confidence');
    $data2 = $statistics->pluck('no_answer');
    $data3 = $statistics->pluck('missing_intent');
    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('labels','data','data1','data2','data3', 'question_asked_sum'));
}
```

Comment: Did you write the above code ? if you have then you should know where to put it 'cos you're the one who know your code not us.